# How do I get archive node access?

Tags: go-ethereum, archive-node

I am trying to figure out how to pull historical data and realised I need access to an archive node.

How do I actually get access to one?

I've tried requesting one from https://archivenode.io to no avail. I've also looked at https://www.quicknode.com - but the archive version costs $250/month.

Is there anything around for a reasonable cost?

Happy New Year!

Comment: http://archivenode.net?